# Setting gzip compression by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, symfony, compression, gzip

I've a problem getting the html/css/js files compression working using gzip on symfony 2.1.7. I've found the `.htaccess` file in the `web` folder, but don't know how to modify it. Can anyone guide me or give me a link on how to go about it?

This is what I currently have in my `.htaccess` file in the web of my symfony project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you are asking for a modification, why don't you post the contents to be modified?

Comment: It has been edited with the contents of the .htaccess file in the web folder. What I don't understand is how to add gzip compression.

Comment: Check [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance/) for one of many good descriptions on how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744982/servergrove-how-to-turn-on-gzip-compression-for-symfony2-site