# How to turn on gzip compression for symfony2 site?

Tags: symfony

I am using servergrove for my site hosting but they sure lack staff that would help me. How do I setup gzip compression for symfony2 site?

If possible, in an idiot-proof way as I have no knowledge of linux.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I add the following into my .htaccess in the web folder.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/richtext
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xsd
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xsl
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
</IfModule>
```

Can't remember for the life of me where I originally got it from.

Comment: Note, you need to ensure that "mod_filter" as well as "mod_deflate" are enabled for this to work.

Comment: I've spent like hour debugging this and then realized that there is a different virtual host config file for https version in sites-available (domain.com-ssl.conf). Leaving this here in case somebody makes same mistake.